# Убрать vt и vn, при экспорте wavefront(.obj) в блендере

Tags: blender, obj

После экспотра модельки карты в формат .obj я получаю такие значения полигонов

```
f 1/1/1 5/2/1 7/3/1 3/4/1
f 4/5/2 3/4/2 7/6/2 8/7/2
f 8/8/3 7/9/3 5/10/3 6/11/3
f 6/12/4 2/13/4 4/5/4 8/14/4
f 2/13/5 1/1/5 3/4/5 4/5/5
f 6/11/6 5/10/6 1/1/6 2/13/6
```

можно ли убрать текстуры и нормали, что бы остались только вершины, примерно так

```
f 1 5 7 3
f 4 3 7 8
f 8 7 5 6
f 6 2 4 8
f 2 1 3 4
f 6 5 1 2
```

и ещё лучше, чтобы у каждого полигона было только 3 вершины

```
f 1 5 7
f 4 3 7
f 8 7 5
f 6 2 4
f 2 1 3
f 6 5 1
f 1 3 7
f 4 8 7
f 8 6 5
f 6 8 4
f 2 4 3
f 6 2 1
```

я понимаю, что так тратится больше места, но мой движок не принимает по другому. Есть ли такие настройки в блендере, или стоит использовать другие редакторы, типо 3д макс?